# Wso2 session timeout configuration irrespective of idle timeout

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In wso2 IS there is idle timeout configuration which expires session if any new authentication request is not recieved but is there any configuration for session expiry irrespective of user activity (not idle time)?. If it is there, How we can configure the session timeout in IDAM.

Comment: What is the use case here. If the user is not idle anyway the session will be not expired and until its idle and if it not reached the idle time out.

Comment: @BuddhimaUdaranga we need to expire the based on idle session and session timeout. If user is not accessing app for x min need to expire session and there will be a global timeout irrespective of user accessing the application. Which will expire after y min.

Comment: You should be able to achive this by configuring the remember me period as the timeout.  After the timeout the session will be not remembered by the identity server and login will be prompted

Comment: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/configuring-session-timeout/#remember-me-period

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, WSO2 IS doesn't support your requirement, OOTB. You'll have to utilize the session management REST API [1] from outside and delete the sessions according to your business needs.

For example, you can run a cron job in a separate server which will pull all active sessions from the API and delete the ones that are not adhering to your requirement. i.e, the ones older than y min.

[1] - https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/session-mgt-rest-api